# jQuery URL Parameter hides list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of a head-scratcher right now.

I'm trying to filter a list based on a URL Parameter that I pass into my function.

The result I'm trying to solve for is if someone manually changes the URL Parameter to 0 it will display the entire list instead of hiding all the list items.

**HTML**

```
<select id="hof-accomp">
  <option value="0">Choose an Award</option>
  <option value="1">Rookie of The Year</option>
  <option value="2">MVP Award</option>
  <option value="3"> DPOY Award</option>
</select>

<ul class="gallery-wrap">
  <li>
     <div class="gallery-footer">
       <span class="counter awardYear hidden">1993</span>
       <span class="counter awardTitle" data-award="1">Rookie of The Year</span>
     </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div class="gallery-footer">
       <span class="counter awardYear hidden">1999</span>
       <span class="counter awardTitle" data-award="2">MVP Award</span>
     </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div class="gallery-footer">
       <span class="counter awardYear hidden">1993</span>
       <span class="counter awardTitle" data-award="3">DPOY Award</span>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQUERY**

```
// gets and filters the URL parameter
function getURLParams(k){
  var p={};
  location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(s,k,v) {
    p[k]=v
  });
  return k ? p[k] : p
}

const awardParam = getURLParams('AwardID');

function awardFilter(awardParam){
  if(awardParam) {
    // Set the dropdown menu to the award name
    const filter = $('#hof-accomp')
                      .find("option[value='"+ awardParam +"']")
                      .prop("selected",true);

    // Filters inductees by URL Parameter
    $('.awardTitle').each(function() {
      let awardData = $(this).data('award');
      let awards = $(this).parentsUntil('.gallery-wrap');

      filter == 0 ? awards.removeClass('hidden') : awards.addClass('hidden');

      awardData != awardParam ? awards.addClass('hidden') : awards.removeClass('hidden');
    });
  }
}
awardFilter(awardParam);
```

Comment: if I understand it right you can expand the condition: `awardData != awardParam && awardParam > 0`. That's it, or?

Comment: When I console log the 'filter' it returns an object. So should I test against the URL Parameter instead?

Comment: sure it returns an object (a jquery collection if you want to be exact). You SET the selected property instead of reading it. remove the `,true` at the line where you define the filter variable.

Comment: ok I got it. Sorry: _When I console log the 'filter' it returns an object. So should I test against the URL Parameter instead?_ yes. absolutly yes. `filter` is a jquery collection but you want to text against the filter variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED jQUERY**

What I found would help is to take in the URL Parameter to set the option value. 
Then filter the list based on the new *selected* option

This correction to my function fixed it.

```
function awardFilter(awardParam){
  if(awardParam) {
  // Set the dropdown menu to the award name
    const awardSelected = $('#hof-accomp').find("option[value='"+ awardParam +"']").prop("selected", true);
    console.log(awardSelected);
    const filter = $('#hof-accomp').val();
    console.log(filter);
  // Filters inductees by URL Parameter
  $('.awardTitle').each(function(){
    let awardData = $(this).data('award');
    let awards = $(this).parentsUntil('.gallery-wrap');

  awardData == awardParam || awardData == filter ? awards.removeClass('hidden') : awards.addClass('hidden');
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: But this code does something different. In your code above (in question) you're *setting* the option to selected state. now you're reading it. That's a different kind of thing. You can achieve both actions or set the property and use the awardParam in your condition.

Comment: I believe you are correct which begs the question. How would I solve for the original question if I'm trying to _set_ the option to selected instead of reading it?

Answer (score 0):

your two conditions are wrong. First of all you can combine them. Second: `filter == 0` is wrong because that never happens. `filter` is a jquery collection. You can change your code in a way like this:

```
function awardFilter(awardParam){
  var awardParam = parseInt(awardParam, 10);
  if(awardParam>-1) {
    // Set the dropdown menu to the award name
    $('#hof-accomp')
        .find("option[value='"+ awardParam +"']")
        .prop("selected",true);

    // Filters inductees by URL Parameter
    $('.awardTitle').each(function() {
      let awardData = $(this).data('award');
      let awards = $(this).parentsUntil('.gallery-wrap');

      awardData != awardParam && awardParam > 0 ? awards.addClass('hidden') : awards.removeClass('hidden');
    });
  }
}
awardFilter(awardParam);
```

But you can shorten your code. Why iterating and choose for each item by yourself?

```
function awardFilter(awardParam){
  var awardParam = parseInt(awardParam, 10);
  if(awardParam<0) return;
  // Set the dropdown menu to the award name
  $('#hof-accomp')
      .find("option[value='"+ awardParam +"']")
      .prop("selected",true);

  // Filters inductees by URL Parameter
  $('.gallery-wrap').children('li').addClass('hidden').filter(function(){
      return awardParam==0 || $(this).find('.awardTitle').data('award') == awardParam;
  }).removeClass('hidden');
}
awardFilter(awardParam);
```

Comment: I like the improvements. By default, the list items don't have the hidden class added on page load.

Comment: If this is the case you can change `if(awardParam<0) return;` to `if(awardParam<1) return;` and remove the `awardParam==0 ||` from the condition

Comment: The gallery-wrap class is the <ul> which I don't want to be hidden if I'm reading your code correctly. Just the individual <li> 's

Comment: @cpt-crunchy if you have any problems feel free to ask. if it's working and it helped you please upvote and select it as the correct answer so I and other users can see that this question is successfully answered.